# Tor browser cannot uninstall

Tags: uninstall, browser, tor

I have tried to uninstall *tor browser* multiple times with no success. When I go into the Ubuntu software uninstaller it doesn't show up. When I right click the tor browser icon and click on show details it will pop up that away. But when I click uninstall, it doesn't do anything. Sometimes it will say it uninstalled it. But then instantly pops up that its currently installed. Also if I cannot install or uninstall anything else in my Ubuntu software. I have tried some terminal commands with no prevail. It keeps saying

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge tor-browser

[sudo] password for mp********: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'tor.list^G' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package tor-browser
```